# Why does startActivityForResult use an Intent to pass data rather than a Bundle?

Tags: android, design-patterns

As you can see from the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#StartingActivities) the way to start an `Activity` to have data passed back is like so:

1. Start the `Activity` using the call `startActivityForResult(Intent intent, int requestCode)`.
2. In the started `Activity` call `setResult(int resultCode, Intent data)`.
3. Implement `onActivityResult(int, int, Intent)` on the calling `Activity`.

The question is: is their a pattern or design consideration for using an `Intent` in this situation where as everywhere else inter-activity data is represented as a `Bundle`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Until I get a more detailed answer the only thing I can think is that this has been done specifically to give the called Activity increased control over the resulting action.

The only scenario I can see where it would be better to be done in this way is if the called Activity was in another sandbox and could construct the Intent using an explicit `Class` reference rather than through the use of an `Action` locking the resulting call to that of the specified explicit `Activity`.

Answer (score 0):

By passing back an intent rather than merely a bundle, the caller can receive something with which to directly start another activity, service, etc. Though that may not be required in all (or even most) cases, it still allows a bundle to be delivered in the intent's extras.

Comment: Since everything but explicit `Intent`s can be expressed/constructed through basic types it seems like this may have been done expressly to place the flow of control on the shoulders of the called `Activity` over the calling one. It just seems very strange that there isn't a very good reason for this...?